# Code not working in Heroku

Tags: php, heroku

I have been working with an php to code to generate image, this code works in my localhost and i hosted in personal website it worked there also . but when i hosted the php code in Heroku it results to SERVER ERROR

The website encountered an error while retrieving http://afternoon-river-7575.herokuapp.com/gen.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

It results an HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error);

Is the problem is about creating file in heroku's file system.

```
<?php

$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);


header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

imagejpeg($im);

imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: might be a dumb question, but do you have the GD extension enabled? Also did you check your apache logs to see what the error actually is?